# Why is this system reversible? What does this mean?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the system
$$
\dot{x}=y,\qquad\dot{y}=-x+y^2.
$$
Then, it is said that the system is reversible $(t\to -t, y\to -y)$. What does this mean?

If I put this into the equations, I get
$$
\dot{x}(-t)=y(-t),\qquad \dot{y}(-t)=-x(-t)+y(-t)^2.
$$

So does reversible mean here that when replacing $t$ by $-t$ and $y$ by $-y$, the differential equations still hold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That the system is reversible indicates there is inherent symmetry in the problem. To show reversibility, you are correct.

Notice that $$\dot{x} = \frac{dx}{dt},\dot{y} = \frac{dy}{dt}$$So$$t\rightarrow -t \Rightarrow (\dot{x} \rightarrow -\dot{x})$$

$$t\rightarrow -t \text{ and } y \rightarrow -y \Rightarrow \dot{y} \rightarrow \dot{y} $$
Getting back to the system, making the given substitution yields,

$$-\dot{x} = -y\Rightarrow \dot{x} = y$$
$$\dot{y} = -x+(-y)^2 \Rightarrow \dot{y} =-x+y^2$$

Comment: Why irreversible in your first sentence?

Comment: It was a typo, I've edited it.

Comment: How do you know that $t \rightarrow -t \Rightarrow (\dot x \rightarrow - \dot x)$?

Comment: Well, dt becomes -dt